# __init__ file imports in custom Python module with submodule

Tags: python

I have a very basic question that I can't seem to find an answer for.

Let's say I have a custom module folder with lots of .py files. And then I have an `__init__.py` file. In that `__init__.py` file, if I were to import standard modules, let's say `import numpy as np` etc.

Is there no way to avoid having to import the same modules in every submodule?

Cheers

Comment: generally speaking, `__init__.py` should contain nothing or imports from sub-modules.

Comment: Yes. The parent directory holding the `__init__.py` is a package name. Assuming you've installed the package (or at least put the parent of this parent directory in PYTHONPATH), its in that module namespace. The stuff in `__init__.py` ends up in the package namespace. If the package is named `foo` and you imported numpy, you'll have `foo.np`.

Comment: __init__ is the first file to be loaded in a module, so you can use it to execute code that you want to run each time a module is loaded.

Comment: But unilaterally importing in `__init__.py` can slow your program down. Are there use cases for importing your package without importing numpy? Its common to include external imports in every module that uses them for better readability later... but that's personal choice.